# vscode-java: picj pom-k3d.xml instead of pom.xml

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

Currently, I've two "`pom.xml`" files into my project:

- `pom-k3d.xml`
- `pom.xml`

`pom-k3d.xml` contains some additional plugins and dependencies.

`vscode` is getting by default `pom.xml`.

1. Is there any way to set `vscode` pick `pom-k3d.xml` file instead?
2. Is there any way to split a "`pom.xml` file into two modular ones?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why having a different pom file? Yes you wrote having additional plugins/dependencies but why a different pom file? Plugins can be configured if not called where is the issue?

Comment: I'm working with two copies of the same project, temporally. I need to keep original `pom.xml` but I need to use another one in order to make some changes without modifying the original one...

Comment: You should using a version control system like Git...